# Can I say "When I become advanced level"?

Tags: phrases

Is this a right expression to say?

> "I'll study it again, when I become advanced level."

The situation was like that, a native speaker explained about the grammar of Thai, but as a beginner I thought it's better to put it off until I can understand better.

How would you say in this case like this?

Comment: Or you may simply say - When I'm better at it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you really mean "advanced level", you might say

> I'll study it again
>   I'll come back to it again
>   I'll look at it again
>   I'll review it again

when

> I am better at *it*
>   I am more proficient
>   I understand more
>   I am more fluent
>   I am more advanced
>   I am less of a beginner

The problem with using "advanced level" is that it might be understood to mean the same as being "fluent", that only until you have a much higher level, since there might be "beginner" and "intermediate" levels to go through before you are "advanced".

Answer (score -1):

I would say either "When I am more advanced" or "When I am at an advanced level".

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well.